# How do you send NULL as a variable from PHP to SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to send a value of "NULL" to a column in mySQL.

```
   $ParentEventID = "NULL";

   mysql_query("UPDATE events SET 
     ParentEventID = '$ParentEventID'");
```

The column keeps defaulting to "0".  I have the column set to accept NULL and I can edit the cell with the NULL check box.

I need to not set the default to NULL because it may effect code in other places.

Comment: +1 For a question that seems like a FAQ but I've never seen it on SO before.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are on the right track making `"NULL"` a string.  If you need to set it `NULL`, then remove the qoutes around `$ParentEventID`.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE events SET ParentEventID = $ParentEventID");
```

However, before doing so make sure that the value of `$ParentEventID === NULL`.

Comment: Great!  That did it.  So...by removing the quotes what exactly is happening?-OK I see quotes make it a string.  Thanks guys.  I will accept your answer when SO lets me-in 10 minutes

Comment: What is happening is that null in SQL is not the string `"NULL"`, but the keyword `NULL`. So you put that, without quotes, into the query. Just the same way you don't put quotes around the `UPDATE` keyword. Remember, you're not really "sending" anything: you're just forming an SQL query in a PHP string.

Comment: @Joel by removing the single-quotes, the string `NULL` is passed in as the MySQL keyword `NULL`.  If you keep the single-quotes as `'NULL'`, MySQL interprets it as a string value. If it is going into an integer column or a boolean column, I guess that's being interpreted as the value '0'.

Comment: If you're expecting a possibility of other values it's a good idea to have quotes for everything other than NULL, even though it's a numeric field. (to prevent SQL injection)